Folder and Printer sharing from Windows 11 to another machine
I have shared a folder and connected it to another machine, which worked before, however now I can only see the folder from the other machine and can't open it:
No more connections can be made to this remote computer at this time because there are already as many connections as the computer can accept


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

What research was done?

Do you still get the error after restarting both computers? It looks like something has too many sessions/open files, or might not be disconnecting properly. If reboot does not fix, then more likely an issue with the service or config

@JW0914, I referred to that thread on the Microsoft Community site on the same day I posted the question. I will try it today.

@Cpt.Whale, Reboot didn't solve the issue. Will update.
